# MySQL check if given timeslot is in between provided timeslot

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have an appointment booking table something like:

```
| id | user_id | guest_name | appointment_date | start_time | end_time |
|----|---------|------------|------------------|------------|----------|
| 1  | 1       | Abc        | 2016-09-30       | 13:00:00   | 13:30:00 |
```

Considering the guest named "Abc" has a booking of an appointment on date `2016-09-30` at `13:00` to `13:30 pm`, I want to check if the provided timeslot (i.e. `13:00-13:30`) on the date `2016-09-30` must not get overlapped with following date time inputs.

```
| appointment_date | start_time | end_time |
|------------------|------------|----------|
| 2016-09-30       | 11:00      | 12:00    |
| 2016-09-30       | 12:30      | 13:00    |
| 2016-09-30       | 13:30      | 14:00    |
| 2016-09-30       | 14:00      | 14:30    |
| 2016-09-30       | 12:45      | 13:15    |
| 2016-09-30       | 13:15      | 13:45    |
| 2016-09-30       | 13:10      | 13:20    |
| 2016-09-30       | 13:00      | 13:25    |
| 2016-09-30       | 13:10      | 13:30    |
| 2016-09-30       | 13:00      | 13:30    |
| 2016-10-01       | 13:00      | 13:30    |
```

Considering following inputs, you may see the slots that starts or ends withing `13:00` to `13:30` are overlapping the record in appointment booking table.

In short, I want a query that returns the records from appointment booking table if start and end time of provided inputs overlaps them.

I have tried following:

```
SELECT * FROM appointments 
WHERE user_id = 1 
AND appointment_date = DATE('2016-09-30') 
AND (   (start_time = '11:00' AND end_time = '12:00') 
    OR 
    (start_time < '11:00' AND end_time > '12:00') 
    OR 
    (start_time > '11:00' AND end_time < '12:00') 
    OR (
    (start_time > '11:00' OR end_time < '11:00') 
    AND 
    (start_time < '12:00' OR end_time < '12:00'))
);
```

But not successful. Does any one know how to check it?

Comment: Can you also post the expected output?

Comment: Simply the record of appointment table i.e. given in table above with Id 1. I want it return the records if the provided input of same date and time does overlap any existing records of the appointment table.

Comment: Perhaps counter-intuitively, this would be slightly simpler (and more efficient) if dates and times were stored as single entities.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes. I agree. But considering current implementation, I cannot change it right now as many other modules are depending upon the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM appointments t1
JOIN dates t2 ON t1.appointment_date = t2.appointment_date AND
                 t1.start_time <= t2.end_time AND
                 t1.end_time >= t2.start_time
```

The above query returns the record of table `appointments` as long as there is *at least one* overlapping record in the other table.

Comment: Let me check with the inputs I have provided in question.

Comment: I have updated it like: ```SELECT t1.*
FROM appointments t1
WHERE t1.appointment_date = DATE('2016-09-30')
AND t1.start_time < '14:00' 
AND t1.end_time > '12:00'``` and it worked for all inputs I've provided. Thanks alot.